# Why is the action link click event not working properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am new to MVC4 and trying to call a partial view to display a pop up to add details. I have a search view which has a link to upload check details. The view and controller for check upload is different than search controller. The action link click event fires when I open the link in new tab (using mouse right click) but the action link does not work when I click on it.Kindly let me know what I am missing. Thanks in advance.

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Upload Check", "CheckUpload", "Transaction", new { @sbiCustSid = Convert.ToString("1"), ordrID = "1", checkDetailID = Convert.ToString("1") }, new { @class = "chkupldlink" })
```

Updating the answer:

```
I have a class chkupldlink which loads the pop up.
   $(".chkupldlink").click(function () {
        loadurl = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
```

Added the div and works fine.

```
<div id="dialog-confirm">

</div>
```

Comment: how you are opening pop up with this actionlink post jquery code also..

Comment: @Exception: Thanks for questioning me about the actionlink post jquery code. I forgot to add the main div in search to display the pop up.I have created a checkupload.cshtml for the pop up.

Comment: That looks like jQuery UI, not Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are implementing pop up in wrong way just do as :

```
 $(".chkupldlink").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    loadurl = $(this).attr('href');
    //make a ajax call here and get html from partial view and append html in your div
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I set fixed size for the pop up since the close button which is placed on the top right is hidden.

Comment: @psobhan...i have not worked much with jqueryui dialog though i worked with bootstrap model..but in my opinion when you are intialising your div '#dialog-confirm' as dialog there only set its height and width..